# Complexity of Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I have an algorithm which searches a sorted int array for two elements which sum up to a searched value. First I thought that the complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n)$, but the interpolation search algorithm has a similar approach and has a $\mathcal{O}(\log(log(n)))$ complexity with uniform distributed elements.

Which is the right complexity and why?

```java
boolean hasPairWithSum(int[] elements, int sum) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = elements.length-1;
    while (start < end) {
      int tempSum = elements[start] + elements[end];
      if (tempSum == sum) return true;
      if (tempSum > sum) {
          end--;
      } else {
          start++;
      }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: O(log log n) ⊊ O(n)

Comment: You may want to [try a structured approach](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works in linear time, because `end - start` decreases by 1 on each iteration. It's $n - 1$ initially, hence the loop will make at most $n - 1$ iterations.